# First form not closing, second not opening

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'd like to have a welcoming form, named the StartForm. This closes, then opens my MenuForm.

Current problem is: First one stays open, doesn't close to show the second one.

I tried several things, like simply showing and hiding them. I now try Application.run and then hide it. Unfortunately it stays open. And doesnt Application.run the second form.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Form StartForm = new Main();
        MForm MenuForm = new MForm();
        Application.Run(StartForm);
        //
        Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            StartForm.Hide();
            Application.Run(MenuForm);
        });
        }
```

I expected this to Close the first form after waiting the delay, but it stays open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Application.Run()` causes a new application message loop to begin running on the current thread. If a subsequent call to `Application.Run()` is made while the first application is running an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netframework-4.7.2). However, this is not actually possible in your case as your call to `Application.Run()` is being invoked on the UI thread, which blocks the execution of any following code until it exits.

Instead, what we need is to bootstrap the application by using `Application.Run(new Main())` and then inside of the `Main` form we will handle the displaying and hiding behaviour.

Here is how I would suggest achieving this:

Firstly, in your `Main` method, replace everything with `Application.Run(new Main());`.

Then inside of your `Main` form create a method like the following:

```
private void Main_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.WaitAll(Task.Delay(500));
    this.Hide();
    var menuForm = new MForm();
    menuForm.Closed += (obj, args) => { this.Show(); };
    menuForm.Show();
}
```

And lastly, go into your `Main.Designer.cs` file and make sure you subscribe the `Shown` event to `Main_Shown` method you just created in the `InitializeComponent` method like so:

`this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Main_Shown);`

Explanation of what is going on here:

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=netframework-4.7.2) the `Form.Shown` Event gets fired the first time a form is shown to the user. This is perfect for this use case, so we 'hook' into it and respond to it by awaiting a delay of 500 milliseconds.

Afterwards we hide the current (`Main`) form, create the new (`MForm`) form and show it. But the more important detail is that we subscribe to **that** form's `Closed` event so that when it is closed by the user, the `Main` form shows itself again.

Comment: So according to you I should where I Hide the startform do Application.Exit()? This doesn't seem to work for me. The StartForm is still open.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, please see my edited post for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use timer to Open Second form in Firstform
and Hide Firstform after show Secondform.

like this.

**Main**

```
static void Main()
{
    Form StartForm = new Main();
    Application.Run(StartForm);
}
```

**FirstForm**

set timer with interval 5000 and Enable it.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MForm MenuForm = new MForm();
    this.Hide();
    MenuForm.Show();
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Using this I got both of them to open, I created a timer with 5000. Called it on the bottom of my FirstForm.